# Normal distribution - How to Calculate When There are Several Variables?

Tags: statistics, normal-distribution

I have this task:

> At a gathering, the contestants are supposed to taste a new product. The time a random contestant uses to taste this product is normally distributed with $\mu = 9\text{ minutes}$ and $\sigma = 3\text{ minutes}$.
>
> a) Five random contestants are sitting around table $1$.  What is the probability that they on average use less than $8$ minutes?
>
> b) What is the probability that exactly four of them use less than $8$ minutes?

I know how to do this for one person, but what do I need to take into consideration when doing this for a group of people?

Thank you!

Comment: **Hint**: If $X\sim\mathcal N(9,9)$, then the average is distributed as $\overline X\sim\mathcal N(9/5,9/5)$.

Answer (score 2):

You know that
$$X_i\sim\mathrm{N}\left(9,3^2\right)$$
for $i=1,2,3,4,5$.

$$\overline{X}=\frac{X_1+X_2+X_3+X_4+X_5}5$$

Hence,

\begin{align}
E\left[\overline{X}\right]&=E\left[\frac{X_1+X_2+X_3+X_4+X_5}5\right]\\
&=\frac{E\left[X_1\right]+E\left[X_2\right]+E\left[X_3\right]+E\left[X_4\right]+E\left[X_5\right]}{5}\\&=\mu=9\end{align}

and

\begin{align}\mathrm{Var}\left[\overline{X}\right]&=\mathrm{Var}\left[\frac{X_1+X_2+X_3+X_4+X_5}5\right]\\&=\frac{\mathrm{Var}\left[X_1\right]+\mathrm{Var}\left[X_2\right]+\mathrm{Var}\left[X_3\right]+\mathrm{Var}\left[X_4\right]+\mathrm{Var}\left[X_5\right]}{5^2}\\&=\frac{\sigma^2}5=\frac{3^2}{5}=\left(\frac{3}{\sqrt5}\right)^2\end{align}

Therefore,
$$\overline{X}\sim\mathrm{N}\left(9,\left(\frac{3}{\sqrt5}\right)^2\right)$$

Your probability for (a) is
$$P\left(\overline{X}<8\right)$$

---

For (b), if you know the binomial distribution, the number of contestants that uses less than $8$ minutes, $Y$, is distributed by
$$Y\sim\mathrm{B}\left(5,P\left({X_i}<8\right)\right)$$

Otherwise, these are the steps:

1. Choose one contestant to use more than or equal to $8$ minutes. There are $$\binom{5}{1}$$ ways to do this.
2. Find the probability of that contestant using more than or equal to $8$ minutes.
   $$P\left({X_a}\ge8\right)$$
3. Find the probability of the other four contestants using less than $8$ minutes.
   $$P\left({X_b}<8\right)P\left({X_c}<8\right)P\left({X_d}<8\right)P\left({X_e}<8\right)$$

Hence, the required probability is
$$\binom{5}{1}P\left({X}\ge8\right)\left(P\left({X}<8\right)\right)^4$$

Comment: Okay, thank you very much!

So the answers should be:

a) P(Z<-0.745)=22.8 %

b) 5C1*0.63*0.37^4=5.9 %

?

Comment: @netwon1227 What have you calculated? Especially, how does $Z<-0.745$ come about?